# How does the first group cohomology classify torsors?

Tags: group-theory, group-cohomology

I know this is true, but I'm having some trouble finding any references on this.

I'm in particular interested in the nonabelian case.

Specifically, let $G$ be a group acting on a group $A$ (both possibly nonabelian). Then $H^1(G,A)$ is defined to be the quotient of the pointed set of functions $f : G\rightarrow A$ satisfying $f(st) = f(s)t(f(t))$ for all $s,t\in G$, by the equivalence relation that $f\sim g$ if there is an $a\in A$ with $g(s) = a^{-1}f(s)s(a)$.

My first question is, can someone describe how this classifies $A$-torsors?

Also, given an action of $G$ on $A$, is there a relationship between $H^1(G,A)$ and $H^1_{\text{triv}}(G,A)$, where the latter is the cohomology with respect to the trivial action of $G$ on $A$? For example, is one of them always contained in the other?

Comment: Do you understand the classical case of $H^1 (X, A)$ classifying principal $A$-bundles on a (nice) space $X$?

Comment: No, though I had always seen group cohomology done from a purely algebraic point of view...

Comment: Pity. Both are special cases of the result for topos cohomology. See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/281086/5191).

Comment: @ZhenLin thanks! thats really helpful.